# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 does not start

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I installed Windows Server 2012 as a VM using Oracle VirtualBox. In this VM MS SQL Server 2012 is running. When starting SQL Server Managment Studio, the splash screen appears for some seconds or minutes. The CPU usage of "SQL Server Management Studio" and "System Interrupts" increases to approximately 20%, where it stays. When ending the SSMS task, the CPU usage of System interrupts falls back to 0%. The GUI of SSMS does not appear. There are no error in the event viewer. 
What i tried so far:

- Uninstall/Install SSMS
- Repaired the installed software
- The software is up to date
- Deleted C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0 to restore the default settings
- Deactivated all SQL Server Services expect "SQL Server"

Other software which is installed: jdk-7u51-windows-x64, apache-tomcat-7.0.50, Ant 1.9.3, Netbeans; However, i can not start SMS after a system reboot and none of these programs are running.

During these days I've been working with this machine, SSMS was running sometimes. However, I spent quite some time to solve this problem and after the last uninstall/install SSMS worked again. This morning i came back and started the server and SSMS didn't start again. Between that I swichted off the machine and enjoyed my weekend off...

Thank you for any hints or solutions!

Comment: Is your SSMS also x64? sometimes this causes problem

Comment: Yes, SQL Server and SSMS is from the dvd with SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition x64 with SP1. So I guess that should be correct.

Answer (score 5):

This also is occurring with my ***Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Version 18.0 (GA)***. I have copied the assembly file name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll" is present in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Interop** and pasted it to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies**. Now SSMS 18 is starting normally.

Comment: This occurred for me, I even had a copy of the dll in the public assemblies folder, but  copying over the private assemblies version, seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to this question here:
[SSMS SQL SERVER Management Studio 2012 startup freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393585/ssms-sql-server-management-studio-2012-startup-freeze/26090204#26090204)

I had the same problem as on that thread but it would start but be unresponsive continuously. In this case there was an issue in the registry:

"However I was successfully after deleting / renaming the regisitry entry: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server]"