# SSMS SQL SERVER Management Studio 2012 startup freeze

Tags: ssms, freeze

I have a strange situation. IT installed SSMS on my laptop and it runs well the first time, connected to my SQL servers remotely etc.   But then it's frozen.   I forced quit and then started SSMS again.  Now it's totally frozen, no popup window at all to enter the server-connection text string.  Then I did a force quit and got a pop up window ([see it here](https://3dafe0ce-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/pictureswlf/imagesql/sqlSSMS%20ERROR.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7cqTad27UGz7s8jhxeDq3Z7vgPTX19BkgFARLxW-vBCfi4HLLztlpSiYgxOoLd6uTKnTbdO6jDFpVOgewO4vdTGvBI6RRrTRp0us6s4uUHcb8wLJta4n-QacqgotPjlucJc291af8Ml5I_CfJhB6C-_d_SfeaKxW6vBWVltNJttwgjAnMGFSlPElQMpUCiHnbNwtAYdRxCnl5OPcneaas_7QS2EZjcCWPCM2zMiHv6he0V-qdYg%3D&attredirects=0) ).

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio has detected that an operation is blocking user input. This can be caused by an active modal dialog or a task that needs to block user interaction. Would you like to shut down anyway?

Has anyone seen this before?  My IT department has no clue.

Comment: Strangely enough, I'm just got this same problem. It was working fine for me yesterday with a very similar scenario today. Did you come across any fix?

Comment: I just ran into the same problem... Did any of you guys solve it?

Comment: Hard to believe this is still an issue 5 years later.

Answer (score 74):

Often this is **due to the new connection dialog being off screen** (usually due to changing monitor setup e.g. 1 to 2 monitors or resolution change etc).

If so the **really easy fix** (if your connection dialog just needed approval without changing fields) is :

1. Focus on SSMS and Hit Enter/Return

..or the **easy fix** (if above does not work - as your last *connection* is not *ready to go*) is:

1. Alt Tab to SSMS
2. Alt + Space - context menu
3. M - select Move (in offscreen context menu)
4. Arrow Key(s) - to move it back onto screen

As per answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/752560/sql-management-studio-hangs-when-opening-after-being-closed-down-on-dual-screen) from @Eirik Toft and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/491222/sql-server-management-studio-2008-has-suddenly-become-unresponsive/491235#491235) from @Lee Chetwynd

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't think about that. This probably happened because one of my monitors is 4K and the others are HD.

Comment: Same here with the 4k monitor.

Comment: Much appreciated, this worked for me. Multi monitor setup. Not sure why the connection dialog went off screen after restart.

Comment: After selecting Move, the dialog will stick to your mouse cursor, so just move your mouse and then click.

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me nuts!!! All I needed to do was to Alt-Tab to the app and press ESC.

Comment: I couldn't get the keyboard actions to do anything, but temporarily unplugging all my external monitors got everything back on track. This should be the answer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes sometimes that's quick, but unplugging monitors doesn't always work - esp for me as I run two 4K screens and one HD all from desktop. Also a pain to reorg. all my windows once back on if I do unplug.

Answer (score 13):

Fixed an issue which presented the same on my machine today by renaming a entry in my registry:

After some digging there seems to be multiple issues that can produce the same error (Application, settings, registry). This blog entry covers it pretty well:
http://www.armedia.com/blog/2012/08/sql-server-management-studio-freeze/

In my case deleteing the SQL server management studio folder under AppData ( c:\users\%userName%Appdata\raoming\microsoft\ ) didn't work.

However I was successfully after deleting / renaming the regisitry entry:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server]

(update)
Worked out the underlying issue on my laptop - was using additional 2 screens with much higher resolutions which caused windows / SSMS to open up the connect to new data source dialog off all of them. If your using multiple screens try returning to just use the native laptop screen to see if you can find the dialog that SSMS is waiting on your input for.

Comment: I killed SSMS, unplugged my external monitors and restarted SSMS. Dialogue came up this time. It seems to be an issue when your laptop screen is not used as the main display.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31549761/661584 for an easier fix than messing with cables & task manager / fiddling with the registry

Comment: @MemeDeveloper Nice! definitely a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same situation, with two additional screens connected to my laptop. SQL Server Management Studio was opened on the third screen, with the modal dialog nowhere to be seen.

Two options:

1. Press tab three times and enter. This cancels the dialog. Now you can move the window to another screen.
2. Set Windows to only use one or two screens. SSMS opens on the first and should still open there when you move back to using three screens.

When SSMS is on your primary or secondary screen, the modal dialog opens on the first and should be usable.

Answer (score 6):

It was because multi screen display. Turning off multiscreen to single one resolved it. Reenabled multi screen display after ssms started working

Comment: In my case there were no extra dialogs, I was able to run scripts, but the toolbar of SSMS was frozen and I was unable to drag window by its title bar.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, "Run as Administrator" option worked like charm. I was accessing my server screen with the windows RDP. And when I open SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio 2010 user hangs at the moment and wont operate unless sign off r disconnected by administrator.

But when I set compatibility mode of both the application to the "run as Administrator", it starts working fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem also occurs if you have a touch screen. I fixed this by disabling the local thouch screen when I switch to RDP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).